# I want to set a variable equal to the index of the clicked item in an array

Tags: javascript, indexof

I am very new to JS and just learning how it works. I have 12 divs and inside of them each is an `div.image` that takes up the whole div and then a `div.info` and `div.date`. I am trying to set it up so that when I click on a div, the info and date will show up and when I click again they disappear. I know this can be done easier with CSS but I wanted to do it with JS.

Currently the function only works for the first `div.info` and `div.date` because I can preset the functions as seen below. I was wondering if there was a way to get the index of the div that I clicked on. Then instead of creating a function for every individual div I can set it to the clicked index.

Here is the javascript code:

```
<script>
    const panels = document.querySelectorAll('.panel');
    console.log(panels);
    const info = document.querySelectorAll('div.info');
    console.log(info);
    const date = document.querySelectorAll('div.date');
    console.log(date);

  function addInfo(){
    document.panels.addEventListener('click', index())

    if(info[0].style.display === 'none'){
      info[0].style.display = 'block'
    } else{
      info[0].style.display = 'none'}
  };

  function addDate(){
    if(date[0].style.display === 'none'){
      date[0].style.display = 'block'
    } else {
      date[0].style.display = 'none'
    }
  };

  document.getElementById("panel1").addEventListener("click", addInfo);
  document.getElementById("panel1").addEventListener("click", addDate);

</script>
```

Comment: Try replacing All `date[0]` with `this` keyword. Like `this.style.display === 'none'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited:
You could get the the element from the click event, and you can reuse this listener for all the elements.

```
function addDate(e){
  const date = e.target
  if(date.style.display === 'none'){
    date.style.display = 'block'
  } else {
    date.style.display = 'none'
  }
};
```

Comment: well if the panels are all contained in a parent element they could just put the event handler on the parent and let it bubble up to be handled there and then they must only bind it once.